# Spine of the player does not LookAt target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

im trying to move my player with WASD controls and make him look into direction of the mouse position. So far i have this

```
public void RotateToMousePosition()
{
    Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(characterInput.MousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo, maxDistance: 300f))
    {
        var target = hitInfo.point;
        target.y = spine.position.y;
        spine.LookAt(target);
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, target, Color.red);
    }
}
 private Vector3 MoveTowardTarget(Vector3 targetVector)
{
    var speed = MovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;       

    targetVector = Quaternion.Euler(0, cam.gameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0) * targetVector;
    var targetPosition = transform.position + targetVector * speed;
    transform.position = targetPosition;
    return targetVector;
}

private void RotateTowardMovementVector(Vector3 movementDirection)
{
    if (movementDirection.magnitude == 0) { return; }
    var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movementDirection);
    hips.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(hips.rotation, rotation, RotationSpeed);
}
```

Which works well, untill i put the animator controller on the player.
Additionally when i am in playmode and i pause the game, i can't manualy manipulate the players spine, the values of the rotation change but not the model.

Thank you for any information or direction you can provide.

Comment: So what does your animator do? Is it just an empty animator controller that causes this behaviour, or do you have any animations added to the controller that set your object's rotation? Also after pausing the game, try disabling the animator component before adjusting the values, this should then visually update your model again

Comment: I just have an idle animation looping. I have tried disabling the animation during playmode and manually change the rotation and it works.

Comment: So...i've had the rotation to mouse position in FixedUpdate. I moved it to LateUpdate and now it works as it should.